# JS Calculate total on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I Have this script that calculates the total of some values as the user selects them from dropdowns. Im no expert with JS. Additionally to onchange I would like this code to calculate the value on page load? I would assume it is some copy and paste of this code with an alteration on the function and an if statement?

```
<script>
$(function() {
     $(".DropChange").change(function(){
        var valone = $('#ValOne').val();
        var valtwo = $('#ValTwo').val();
        var valthree = $('#ValThree').val();
        var valfour = $('#ValFour').val();
        var valfive = $('#ValFive').val();
        var valsix = $('#ValSix').val();
        var valseven = $('#ValSeven').val();
        var valeight = $('#ValEight').val();
        var total = ((valone * 1) + (valtwo * 1) + (valthree * 1) + (valfour * 1) + (valfive * 1) + (valsix * 1) + (valseven * 1) + (valeight * 1));
        $('#Total').text(total);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: JAVASCRIPT IS NOT JAVA!!!

Comment: Copy-paste the same code is usually a bad habit; you can do a function containing your script, like calcTotal() and call it in change event and on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your simplest option is to stick the current `onchange` function into another function.

```
var calculateTotals = function(){    
    var valone = $('#ValOne').val();
    var valtwo = $('#ValTwo').val();
    var valthree = $('#ValThree').val();
    var valfour = $('#ValFour').val();
    var valfive = $('#ValFive').val();
    var valsix = $('#ValSix').val();
    var valseven = $('#ValSeven').val();
    var valeight = $('#ValEight').val();
    var total = ((valone * 1) + (valtwo * 1) + (valthree * 1) + (valfour * 1) + (valfive * 1) + (valsix * 1) + (valseven * 1) + (valeight * 1));
    $('#Total').text(total);
};
```

Then change your `onchange` to

```
$(".DropChange").change(calculateTotals);
```

So your `$(function(){ ... });` now looks like;

```
$(function(){
    $(".DropChange").change(calculateTotals); // assign event
    calculateTotals(); // calculate totals on load
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
<script>
(function() {
     $(document).ready(function(){
        showSum();
      });

      $(".DropChange").change(function(){
          showSum();
      }
      function showSum(){
            var valone = $('#ValOne').val();
            var valtwo = $('#ValTwo').val();
            var valthree = $('#ValThree').val();
            var valfour = $('#ValFour').val();
            var valfive = $('#ValFive').val();
            var valsix = $('#ValSix').val();
            var valseven = $('#ValSeven').val();
            var valeight = $('#ValEight').val();
            var total = ((valone * 1) + (valtwo * 1) + (valthree * 1) + (valfour * 1) + (valfive * 1) + (valsix * 1) + (valseven * 1) + (valeight * 1));
        $('#Total').text(total);
      }
}());
</script>
```

Comment: This _$(function() {_ is equivalent to _$(document).ready(function(){_ see: http://api.jquery.com/ready/